# Is there a way to detect ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED by a built in method in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to detect ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED by a built-in method in Angular 2+ so I can warn the user? Or perhaps thru JS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure about Angular, but the Navigator interface exposed on the global `window` object has a method for determining whether or not a browser is working online.

`navigator.onLine` returns a Boolean indicating whether the browser is working online. Doesn't get any simpler than that. Read the [DOM docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) for a more detailed description.

Example implementation:

```
if(navigator.onLine) { // true|false
    // ...
}
```

In addition to checking for the property value, you can hook into offline and online events:

```
window.addEventListener('online', (e) => console.log(e, "you're online"));
window.addEventListener('offline', (e) => console.log(e, "you're offline"));
```

Then, if the user goes offline, you can freeze the UI, show relevant messages or provide an offline experience (e.g., save data to localStorage until user comes online).

Answer (score 3):

I use the following method

define in your class `online$: Observable<boolean>;`

and inside constructor

```
this.online$ = Observable.merge(
  Observable.of(navigator.onLine),
  Observable.fromEvent(window, 'online').mapTo(true),
  Observable.fromEvent(window, 'offline').mapTo(false)
)
```

also add the imports

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Use it in template

```
<p *ngIf="(online$ | async) == false" >
  <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not connected to internet.
  </ngb-alert>
</p>
```

you can also use it as a service.

Comment: I am using this in angular 4, but sure it will work in angular 2.

Comment: can we use `Observable.concat` instead of merge?

Comment: Hareesh, isn't just using if ( navigator.onLine ) {} so much easier?

Comment: Also `this.online$` returns an `Observable` , you need to subscribe to it to get it's value otherwise it's not possible to detect the changes

Comment: hmm in plain JS, i din't try that. i think that would be much easier.

Comment: @Niladri `Observable.concat` , i think both doesn't make much difference because its simple boolean  expression, i am not sure though.

Comment: Hareesh, if we go with the simple approach, where would you place the window.addEventListener? index.html? Cause that's the only one I can think as the over-arching file (that has the best birds-eye view ) of the entire app.

Comment: Yes, but i prefer in top of my `app.component.html`  where all my other components are loaded.